# Running excel automation on window server 2008 r2 got InteropServices.COMException

Tags: com, automation, excel-2007

My application was running on following environment

- Window Server 2008 R2 64bits
- Microsoft Office 2007
- IIS7

I did some way to solved that kind of problem.
Making the **`Desktop`** folder under **`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\`**

and also

- Run **`dcomcnfg`**.
- Right click Properties on the node **`Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config\Microsoft Excel Application`**.
- Under the **`Security`** tab, under **`Launch and Activation Permissions`** select the **`Customize`** option and click the **`Edit`** button and grant your service account **`Local Launch`** and **`Local Activation`**.

But none of above ways can solve problem. Any thought?

Comment: There are serious issues with trying to do that. Please make sure you read and understand every point in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757, which really boils down to "It is a really, *really* bad idea". You will be restarting your server a lot. Also, notice the license restrictions: even if you make it work, every user of you site must have a valid license to run the same version of Excel you are exposing (a non-starter for Internet sites, but usually Ok for Intranet). If you have SharePoint, Look at Excel Services for how to run a supported subset of Excel in a server environment.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Now I changed to NPOI npoi.codeplex.com to avoid that kind of problem. Do have any suggestion for me?